# "My computer isn't working" or "My computer doesn't work"

Tags: present-tense

My friend is working as computer engineer, I phoned him and ask him the following:

> 1. My computer isn't working, Could you repair it?
> 2. My computer doesn't work, Could you repair it?

Which one is more common in this context? *present simple* or *present continuous *?

Comment: You probably meant **continuous** rather than *contentious*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are fine, but "isn't working" sounds like the problem is *temporary*, and more *fixable*.  "Doesn't work" feels more serious, or long-term.

Still, the exact meaning depends on the context of the rest of the sentence.

> My car doesn't work.  Let's take yours.  (My car has been broken for a while).
>
> My car doesn't work.  I don't know what happened, since it was fine this morning (it's temporarily broken).